# linear-gradient effect doesnt work on another page- probably missing css code

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a linear-gradient on html.

on this web page:
http://unlockdesizn.com/html/health-and-beauty/be-medical/demo/page-department.html

when you hover doctor slider, there is a gradient effect on picture.

[image]

I converted the slider to a wordpress plugin but probably I miss some css code and gradient effect doesnt work on this page:

https://www.video.helvatica.com/

how to solve?

```
.team-grid .thumb:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -75%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3) 100%);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    transform: skewX(-25deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add hover css and animation css. please add below css and check it.

```
.team-grid:hover .thumb:before {
    -webkit-animation: shine .85s;
    animation: shine .85s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  100% { left: 125%; } 
}
@keyframes shine {
  100% { left: 125%; }
}
```